# Fixing table for gtsummary in R

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to create a table using gtsummary. To give some insight, here is my current code so far:

```
# variables associated with Interpreter Use
table1 <- tbl_summary(pre_int, include = c('Age', 'Gender_Identity'), 
by = 'Interpreter Used') %>%
add_n() %>% 
modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>% 
bold_labels() %>% add_p()
```

I am getting the following output as an example:
[image]

I want to add a few things to the code:

1. Fix the percentages such that they display to two significant digits
2. Get the p-values generated for the subcategories rather than just the main categories (for example generating a p-value for gender identity female, male, etc.)
3. Get the mean and SD for age rather than median and IQR.

Any help on how to format the code in order to add these changes? Would appreciate any help. I've tried to look at the documentation but I wasn't able to adapt this code accordingly.

To experiment, here's some sample data:

| Age | Gender Identity | Interpreter Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | White non-Hispanic | Yes |
| 15 | Other | No |
| 8 | Black non-Hispanic | No |
| 10 | White non-Hispanic | No |
| 8 | White non-Hispanic | Yes |
| 15 | White non-Hispanic | Yes |

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your second point? I'm not sure what the request is

Comment: Hi there, I've edited my question to make it more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Fix the percentages such that they display to two significant digits

Use the argument `tbl_summary(digits = all_categorical() ~ c(0, 2)`

> 2. Get the p-values generated for the subcategories rather than just the main categories (for example generating a p-value for gender identity female, male, etc.)

P-values are added an a per-variable basis. To get a p-value for each level of a categorical variable, you must create dummy variables for each level, then add them to the table.

> 3. Get the mean and SD for age rather than median and IQR.

Use the argument `tbl_summary(statistic = age ~ "{mean} ({sd})")`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Do you know how best to fix this error: There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'Gender_Identity', p-value omitted:
Error in stats::chisq.test(x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, : 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels?

Comment: I looked up some debugging tips and tried to change the command within add_p such as trying different tests, but it didn't seem to work

Comment: I suggest posting a new issue with a minimal reproducible example, a reprex, which includes both data and.code that illustrate your issue. Your first debugging step should be running the test outside of gtsummary. The error message seems pretty clear that you don't have 2 levels